# How to combine two arrays of different length into an associative multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, array-merge

I have 2 arrays which are being generated by the `explode()` function.

This array:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => uploads/str/evidence/Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf
        [1] => uploads/str/evidence/keputusantahun1.pdf 
        [2] => uploads/str/evidence/permohonan.pdf 
        [3] => uploads/str/evidence/Invoice_INVCZ7698851.pdf 
        [4] => uploads/str/evidence/keputusantahun11.pdf 
        [5] => uploads/str/evidence/permohonan1.pdf 
        [6] => uploads/str/evidence/Invoice_INVCZ7698852.pdf 
        [7] => uploads/str/evidence/Invoice_INVCZ7698853.pdf 
        [8] => uploads/str/evidence/keputusantahun12.pdf 
    )
```

and this array:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf 
        [1] => Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf 
        [2] => Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf 
        [3] => Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf 
        [4] => Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf 
        [5] => Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf 
        [6] => Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf 
        [7] => Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf 
)
```

My question is how can I merge these arrays into this:

```
Array (
    [imgs] =>
        Array(
            [img] => uploads/str/evidence/Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf,
            [file] => Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf
        ),
    [imgs] =>
        Array(
            [img] => uploads/str/evidence/Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf,
            [file] => Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf
        ),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mismatch in array sizes.  I don't know if that was a posting error, but I have adjusted my code to suit what is literally in the question.  If your arrays are *actually* evenly sized, then I can just rollback my edits to my first posted answer.

Input:

```
$a1=[
     'uploads/str/evidence/Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf',
     'uploads/str/evidence/keputusantahun1.pdf',
     'uploads/str/evidence/permohonan.pdf', 
     'uploads/str/evidence/Invoice_INVCZ7698851.pdf', 
     'uploads/str/evidence/keputusantahun11.pdf', 
     'uploads/str/evidence/permohonan1.pdf', 
     'uploads/str/evidence/Invoice_INVCZ7698852.pdf', 
     'uploads/str/evidence/Invoice_INVCZ7698853.pdf', 
     'uploads/str/evidence/keputusantahun12.pdf'
    ];
$a2=[
     'Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf',
     'Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf',
     'Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf', 
     'Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf', 
     'Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf', 
     'Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf', 
     'Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf', 
     'Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf'
    ];
```

Method ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2ac4b898bc5099511e6d5ab00310cb9b1be4bf58)):

```
foreach($a1 as $i=>$v){
    $result['imgs'][$i]['img']=$v;
    if(isset($a2[$i])){$result['imgs'][$i]['file']=$a2[$i];}
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'imgs' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'img' => 'uploads/str/evidence/Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf',
      'file' => 'Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'img' => 'uploads/str/evidence/keputusantahun1.pdf',
      'file' => 'Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'img' => 'uploads/str/evidence/permohonan.pdf',
      'file' => 'Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'img' => 'uploads/str/evidence/Invoice_INVCZ7698851.pdf',
      'file' => 'Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf',
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
      'img' => 'uploads/str/evidence/keputusantahun11.pdf',
      'file' => 'Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf',
    ),
    5 => 
    array (
      'img' => 'uploads/str/evidence/permohonan1.pdf',
      'file' => 'Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf',
    ),
    6 => 
    array (
      'img' => 'uploads/str/evidence/Invoice_INVCZ7698852.pdf',
      'file' => 'Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf',
    ),
    7 => 
    array (
      'img' => 'uploads/str/evidence/Invoice_INVCZ7698853.pdf',
      'file' => 'Invoice_INVCZ769885.pdf',
    ),
    8 => 
    array (
      'img' => 'uploads/str/evidence/keputusantahun12.pdf',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Hi mickmackusa, works like a charm.. thanks a lot your help, really appreciate it.